# Как выбрать только одну строку из таблицы с внешним соединением?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Есть две таблицы.

Пользователи:

| USER_ID | USER_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Иван1 |
| 2 | Иван2 |
| 3 | ИванЗ |
| 4 | Иван4 |
| 5 | Иван5 |

Телефоны:

| USER_ID | USER_PHONE | PHONE_MAIN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | +79999999999 | 1 |
| 1 | +78888888888 | 0 |
| 2 | +77777777777 | 1 |
| 2 | +76666666666 | 0 |
| 3 | +75555555555 | 0 |
| 4 | +74444444444 | 1 |

Необходимо объединить эти две таблицы в одну, но при этом телефон должен подвязаться только один раз, с условием, что если если есть основной (`phone_main=1`), то присоединить эту запись, если основного нет, то присоединить не основной (`phone_main=0`)

Как можно сделать оптимизированный запрос, чтобы итоговая таблица получилась такой:

| USER_ID | USER_NAME | USER_PHONE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Иван1 | +79999999999 |
| 2 | Иван2 | +77777777777 |
| 3 | ИванЗ | +75555555555 |
| 4 | Иван4 | +74444444444 |
| 5 | Иван5 | пусто |

Есть ли возможность в `join` сделать проверку?

```
select tu.user_id, tu.user_name, tp.user_phone
from table_user tu
left join table_phone tp on tp.user_id=tu.user_id and (tp.phone_main = 1 or tp.phone_main = 0)
```

Вышеуказанный код возвращает две строки, т.к. `or` учитывает и то и другое.

Пока только такое решение нашел:

```
select tu.user_id, tu.user_name, coalesce(tp1.user_phone, tp2.user_phone)
from table_user tu
left join table_phone tp1 on tp1.user_id=tu.user_id and tp1.phone_main = 1
left join table_phone tp2 on tp2.user_id=tu.user_id and tp2.phone_main = 0
```

Comment: MySQL не поддерживает PL/SQL. Удалите лишний тег.

Comment: Поправил, спасибо, MySQL был лишний

Comment: А  PL/SQL разве не лишний? В вопросе он никак не упомянут. Почитайте в описании метки, что это такое.

Comment: За приведённые в текстовом виде данные, плюс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> при этом телефон должен подвязаться только один раз

То есть задача, взять из связаной таблицы только *первую* подходящую запись.

Решение со стандартным соединением:

```
select u.user_id, u.user_name, p.user_phone
from table_users u
left join (
    select user_id, 
        max (user_phone) keep (dense_rank first order by phone_main desc) user_phone
    from table_phone
    group by user_id) p on p.user_id=u.user_id
/
```

Или более эффективно с  коррелированным соединением таблиц:

```
select u.user_id, u.user_name, p.user_phone
from table_users u
outer apply (
    select max (user_phone) keep (dense_rank first order by phone_main desc) user_phone
    from table_phone p
    where p.user_id=u.user_id) p
/
```

Оба запроса вернут ожидаемый результат (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f7f6e87d4a5a3f9fac7b208c672d642e)):

```
  USER_ID USER_NAME    USER_PHONE  
---------- ------------ ------------
         1 Иван1        +79999999999
         2 Иван2        +77777777777
         3 ИванЗ        +75555555555
         4 Иван4        +74444444444
         5 Иван5        пусто
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте коррелированный подзапрос:

```
SELECT tu.user_id, 
       tu.user_name, 
       ( SELECT tp.user_phone
         FROM table_phone tp
         WHERE tp.user_id=tu.user_id
         ORDER BY phone_main DESC LIMIT 1 ) user_phone
FROM table_user tu
```

А для PL/SQL используйте оконную функцию. Например:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT tu.user_id, 
       tu.user_name, 
       tp.user_phone, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tp.user_id ORDER BY tp.phone_main DESC) rn
FROM table_user tu
LEFT JOIN table_phone tp ON tp.user_id=tu.user_id
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: _А для PL/SQL используйте оконную функцию_, это как? В  PL/SQL нет оконных функций.